# As a team, what is the best way to counter deflection/absorption abilities on the enemy team?

Tags: overwatch-2

This is a rather frustrating problem to me -- how as a team, or perhaps even in individual roles can I take on heroes that have some core part of their kit around deflecting/absorbing damage, often reflecting it back.  For instance, I've noticed a LOT of teams running a composition of tanks like Sigma/D.va/Orisa, damage dealers like Genji, and supports like Kiriko which offer brief invulnerability periods. It feels immensely cancerous when they cycle their skills in tandem so you never feel like you have a window to get damage in.

I know there are heroes that have abilities/weapons that can do damage that bypasses some of these abilities, like Winston's zappy gun or Mei's freezy gun.   But acting alone often isn't enough to stop a well-coordinated team running a synergistic line-up.

As a team, what is the best way to counter deflection/absorption abilities on the enemy team?

Comment: You've sort of answered it yourself.. a team comp with Winston's zappy gun, or Zarya's beamy gun, Mei's freezy gun, Symmetra's different beamy gun, etc. The game is about picking and counter picking.Cycling abilities in tandem is the way a coordinated team plays, so another option is to find groups to play with.

Comment: There's also only a limited number of these heroes, so they can't rotate them indefinitely.  You can also use damage dealers that can get behind the enemy to deal with them since most of those abilities are directional (shields, Genji's Deflect, Sigma's damage absorb, Orisa's javelin spin)

Comment: @Powerlord I meant rotating skill effects as in Orisa will do her damage absorption thing, then when that's over, Genji will step in and cast Deflect, and then the cycle repeats.

Comment: @childe Right, but all of these skills have cooldowns.  There will always be an opening and, as I already pointed out, these skills are directional.

Comment: @Powerlord Tell me, are those openings long enough for you to deal enough damage that their supports can't outheal?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that role queue in Overwatch 2 has a single tank (instead of two).

Comment: @NickMcCurdy And 2 supports. There seems to be barely enough damage windows on a tank like Orisa or Sigma in between Fortify, Shields, and other damage mitigation that they do (not to mention the aformentioned DPS units) to really make a dent in their hp.